# Controlling gradle runtime dependencies with build parameter

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, shadowjar

I use Gradle and its ShadowJar plugin to build a fat jar for my application, which is deployed in one of two contexts.

In one context, the environment provides dependencies A,B and C (and all their transitive dependencies), and these classes should not be part of my fat jar.

In the other context, the environment only provides dependencies A and B and I must ensure that C and all its transitive dependencies are bundled in my fat jar.

How can I define this behaviour in my Gradle build file? I think the best way would be to adjust the `runtime.exclude` property somehow based on a build target or command-line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So I think your looking for two configurations.

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compileOnly group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '20.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output, configurations.compile
    baseName = "$project.name-fat"
}

jar.dependsOn fatJar
```

Now we can create a jar for each context we are interested in deploying to

```
$ ./gradlew clean build
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:fatJar
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.997 secs
```

now lets verify that we have a fat jar

```
$ unzip build/libs/q40727142-fat.jar -d build/libs/included
Archive:  build/libs/q40727142-fat.jar
   creating: build/libs/included/META-INF/
  inflating: build/libs/included/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
   creating: build/libs/included/com/
   creating: build/libs/included/com/jbirdvegas/
   creating: build/libs/included/com/jbirdvegas/q40727142/
  inflating: build/libs/included/com/jbirdvegas/q40727142/Hello.class  
  inflating: build/libs/included/groovy-all-2.4.7.jar  
  inflating: build/libs/included/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
```

And lets verify the original configuration does not have our jars as they are expected to be provided.

```
$ unzip build/libs/q40727142.jar -d build/libs/notIncluded
Archive:  build/libs/q40727142.jar
   creating: build/libs/notIncluded/META-INF/
  inflating: build/libs/notIncluded/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
   creating: build/libs/notIncluded/com/
   creating: build/libs/notIncluded/com/jbirdvegas/
   creating: build/libs/notIncluded/com/jbirdvegas/q40727142/
  inflating: build/libs/notIncluded/com/jbirdvegas/q40727142/Hello.class
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a build file that looks like this:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "scala"
    version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    group = "com.example.projects"
    ext.deployEnv = "Env1"

    if (project.hasProperty("deployEnv")) {
        ext.deployEnv= project.property("deployEnv")
    }
}

project(":myproject") {
    configurations {
        runtime.exclude group: 'A'
        runtime.exclude group: 'B'
    }

    if (ext.deployEnv == 'Env0') {
        configurations {
            runtime.exclude group:'C'
        }
    }
}
```

It does what I want, with minimal changes to the build file.